# Populate 1 form field based on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there an easy way to populate one form field with duplicate content from another form field?

Maybe using jQuery or javascript?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just have to assign the field values:

```
// plain JavaScript
var first = document.getElementById('firstFieldId'),
    second = document.getElementById('secondFieldId');

second.value = first.value;

// Using jQuery
$('#secondFieldId').val($('#firstFieldId').val());
```

And if you want to update the content of the second field *live*, you could use the `change` or `keyup` events to update the second field:

```
first.onkeyup = function () { // or first.onchange
  second.value = first.value;
};
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#firstFieldId').keyup(function () {
  $('#secondFieldId').val(this.value);
});
```

Check a simple example [here](http://jsbin.com/atiya).

Answer (score 5):

In Native Javascript:

```
var v1 = document.getElementById('source').value;
document.getElementById('dest').value = v1;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is easy in javascript using jQuery:

```
$('#dest').val($('#source').val());
```

Comment: Thanks Darwin. How would I trigger it so that when I have filled in say the email address field, then click inside the user name field, it adds the email address to the username field.